# Locate character values in a list with a certain pattern and create a new

Tags: r, character

I have a problem. I  have the following character vector:

```
samples <- c("Ssa#STIR23728", "Ssa#STIR16345", "Omy#TC149733", "Ssa#S30265704", "Ssa#EG871857", "Omy#BX307934", "Omy#BE859148",
             "Omy#CA358602","Ssa#EG933893", "Ssa#S30235521", "Ssa#STIR20818", "Ssa#STIR20525", "Ssa#KSS4270", "Ssa#TC106594",
             "Omy#CX066437",  "Ssa#CB506768", "Ssa#STIR06626", "Omy#CA358951", "Ssa#KSS3114_S", "Ssa#DW583553", "Ssa#DW552584",
              "Ssa#KSS4345", "Ssa#STIR16873", "Ssa#DY699188", "Ssa#S35660380", "Ssa#EG781190", "Ssa#S31998243",
             "Ssa#STIR23611", "Ssa#STIR20000")
```

I need to create a new character vector where to assign a new name ("target_Stir") to the names that contain the string "STIR", the name "Trout" to the ones that start with "Omy" while the remaining call them "control". I have used the following approach:

```
is.sample <- function(x) {
  if(grepl("STIR", samples,ignore.case = T ))
    return("Target_Stir")
  if(grepl("Omy", samples,ignore.case = T ))
    return("Trout")
  else 
    return("control")
}
    labels <- lapply(samples, FUN=is.sample)
```

However, I get back a vector with all "control" and warning messages similar to the following:

```
In if (grepl("STIR", control, ignore.case = T)) return("target") else ("control") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I am a junior R user, can someone tell me what am i doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this? Consider i am only showing a subset of my data as an example but i have a long vector (length = 45000) and more than 3 classes. For simplicity I am presenting a short example.

Thanks, Christian

Answer (score 0):

`grepl` is *vectorised* and returns a logical vector of matches and not matches. You don't need to loop along a vector using a vectorised function. You can use `grepl` to subset your `samples` vector and set them to the desired values.

```
ids <- grepl( "STIR" , samples , ignore.case = TRUE )
samples[ ids ] <- "target"
samples[ !ids ] <- "control"
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, however i think that in making my example i over simplified as i have more than two classes in the entire vector. Can you suggest a way to achieve the same with more than two classes? Thanks

Comment: @ChristianD I think you should update the question with an example of how you have the multiple patterns and replacement values. There will be a number of ways of doing this.

Comment: HI Simon, i have edited my orginal question making it more representative of my entire dataset. I dont think it should make much difference if i then have a few more groups as i could use the same approach. Thanks for the patience!